# KiCad footprint for a diode

Tags: circuit-design, datasheet, footprint

How do I determine what kind of footprint is needed for the RBR20NS60A diode? Its datasheet is [linked here.](https://www.rohm.com/products/diodes/schottky-barrier-diodes/low-vf/rbr20ns60a-product)

Comment: Thank you, Aeden :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datasheet states the footprint, right on top of the first page:

- Package Code TO-263S
- JEITA Code SC-83
- ROHM Code TO-263S

So, that's your footprint. Look for TO-263S or SC-83.

Either your EDA tool has a footprint like that, or you'll have to design it yourself; no big deal, really, in Kicad that's not very hard; page 6 of the datasheet shows the recommended pad pattern.

Comment: would TO-263-2 be okay? Or it has to be exactly TO-263S?

Comment: you can compare kicad's footprint to the drawing on page 6.

Comment: When it comes to PCB design, expect to use a micrometer/caliper frequently to verify that the physical packages match footprint dimensions.  Do not rely on the software alone!  "Measure twice, build once."

Comment: @AedenSchmidt the -2 on the end of that just means that it's two pads; this is relatively common nomenclature.